# Multi-line curl in windows command line - each line gets executed line by line rather than whole statement at once

Tags: windows, curl, cmd

Consider this:

```
curl -XPUT 'localhost:9200/customer/external/1?pretty' -d '
{
  "name": "John Doe"
}'
```

I copy and past the above into my cmd line and rather than executing the whole statement it executes:

```
curl -XPUT 'localhost:9200/customer/external/1?pretty' -d '
```

Then

```
{
```

Then

```
 "name": "John Doe"
```

Then

```
}
```

Which leads to errors. Also, the ' quote is being interpreted literally. So for curl -XUPT 'localhost it literally looks for 'localhost rather than localhost.

I am using windows server 2008. And I am using curl installed from here: http://curl.haxx.se/latest.cgi?curl=win64-ssl-sspi

Any tips please?

Thanks